# Create a temporary interface into an object?

Tags: c++, class, interface

I have an object "`World obj;`" that has a normal interface of methods for it's typical funcitonality, but I want to have an additional interface of methods specifically for initializing that should only be visible when I specifically need them.

An example might be like this:

```
class World{
public:
    void draw();
    void update();
    void normalStuff();

    void addATree(); // this should not be ordinarily available or visible,
    void addACar();  // calling this might break the object 
    void addAClown();// if it's not in a ready state for it
private:
    int m_data;
};
```

Is there a way to relatively hide `addATree(); etc` in a way that makes sense?  Ideally the mechanism for revealing those methods would also put the object into a ready state for them, or at least fault if it's not possible.

Comment: Make the functions as robust as possible to react on such cases that if the object is not in the state, that the result of the function is valid.

Comment: How about a `WorldBuilder` class, which have all the `addX` functions, and is used only for adding stuff to the world. Then when the `World` object is fully initialized, you have a `getWorld` function which returns the `World` object, and then you can discard the `WorldBuilder` object. The `WorldBuilder` class could possibly be a `friend` of the `World` class, to be able to modify the internal data of `World` objects.

Comment: Your description is a bit hand-wavy. Can you show a use case? What does "specifically need them" mean?

Comment: Maybe upvote some of the answers people obviously put effort into and maybe accept one if you find a suitable one?

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches would be possible:

### Don't change the code, just change the spec

No need to change the code. Change the API specification and if the caller throws garbage in he gets garbage out.

### Make the functions check if they are allowed

Always safe.

```
class World{
public:
...
    void addAClown() {
        if(not allowed)
            throw error or crash or output error message or just return;
        else {
            do the work;
        }
    }
private:
    int m_data;
};
```

### Write a function that only exposes the Interface if allowed

You can't protect against someone getting the interface early and use it longer than allowed.

You could extract the interface functions into a separate class.

```
class WorldInterfaceToProtect {
public:
    void addATree() = 0; // this should not be ordinarily available or visible,
    void addACar() = 0;  // calling this might break the object 
    void addAClown() = 0;// if it's not in a ready state for it
};
```

then the main class can protect these functions.

```
class World : protected WorldInterfaceToProtect {
public:
    void draw();
    void update();
    void normalStuff();

protected:
    void addATree(); // this should not be ordinarily available or visible,
    void addACar();  // calling this might break the object 
    void addAClown();// if it's not in a ready state for it
private:
    int m_data;
};
```

You then need to add a function that exposes the interface.

```
class World ... {
public:
    WorldInterfaceToProtect *GetInterface() { return allowed_cond ? this : nullptr; }
...
}
```

### Separate the class itself and the builder

This only helps if the functions to be called are only allowed during construction and not later. Depending on the design of the builder you can get a good protection.

```
class World{
friend class WorldBuilder;

public:
    void draw();
    void update();
    void normalStuff();

protected:
    void addATree(); // this should not be ordinarily available or visible,
    void addACar();  // calling this might break the object 
    void addAClown();// if it's not in a ready state for it

private:
    int m_data;
};

class WorldBuilder {
    static World *Build(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps split the world into more composable parts:

```
struct WorldInterface
{
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void normalStuff() = 0;
};

class World : public WorldInterface
{
public:
    void draw() override { /* actual drawing here */};
    void update() override {};
    void normalStuff() override {};

private:
    int m_data;
};

class TreeWorld : public WorldInterface
{
public:
    // takes a reference to the actual world engine and defers work to
    // that
    TreeWorld(World& worldEngine) : worldEngine_(worldEngine) {}

    void draw() override { worldEngine_.get().draw(); };

    void update() override { worldEngine_.get().update(); };

    void normalStuff() override { worldEngine_.get().normalStuff(); };

    void addATree() {
        //do tree/world interaction here
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<World> worldEngine_;
};

class CarWorld : public WorldInterface
{
public:
    // takes a reference to the actual world engine and defers work to
    // that
    CarWorld(World& worldEngine) : worldEngine_(worldEngine) {}

    void draw() override { worldEngine_.get().draw(); };

    void update() override { worldEngine_.get().update(); };

    void normalStuff() override { worldEngine_.get().normalStuff(); };

    void addACar() {
        //do car/world interaction here
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<World> worldEngine_;
};


extern void play_tree_game(TreeWorld world);
extern void play_car_game(CarWorld world);

int main()
{
    World worldEngine;

    // initialise engine here


    // play tree-phase of game         
    play_tree_game(TreeWorld(worldEngine));

    // play car phase of game
    play_car_game(CarWorld(worldEngine));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answers all around, I'll just add this because it was missing(?)

```
class World{
public:
    void draw();
    void update();
    void normalStuff();
private:
    int m_data;
};

class BuildableWorld : public World
{
public:
    void addATree();
    void addACar();
    void addAClown();
};
```

Use the BuildableWorld at initialization phase and then just give a pointer to the base class type for others to use.

Sure, you need some way to give the "built" data for the base class to access, but that was not the issue here, right?

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach that has not been mentioned so far, may be to let addX() functions take parameters whose existence implies that World is in a valid state. Say, if you cannot add trees to a world without water, let World return an (optional) water object to pass to addTree ... in other words, you need to properly formalize World invariants:

```
class World{
public:
    void normalStuff();

    auto getAvaliableWaterBuckets() -> optional<WaterBuckets>;
    auto getAvaliableSoil() -> optional<SoilPack>;
    //...

    void addATree( WaterBuckets&&, SoilPack&& );
    //...
};

// in the meanwhile, in user land:

if( auto water = world->getAvaliableWaterBuckets() )
if( auto soil = world->getAvaliableSoil() )
    world->addTree( std::move(*water), std::move(*soil) );
else
    world->recycleWater( std::move(*water) );
```

the benefit of this approach is that the user is not forced to think about world state validity ( an error prone task ), he just thinks about what he needs in order to add a tree ( simpler, hard to use incorrectly ). Moreover, this scales well because addX() functions can share different objects ( addFlowers needs water, ... ) enabling the correct management of a possibly complex internal world state.

Of course, IMHO, if you need to use addX() *strictly* on world construction only ( and you don't plan to add trees later ), then the factory approach already mentioned in the comments seems the way to go ...